# Input field value not binding to model parameters Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass values from front-end form to backend model.

here is my front-end code:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="timeCard" method="post">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <form:input path="shiftId" type="hidden" id="shiftId" 
            value="${timeCard.shiftId}"  />
        <form:input path="isTimeCardSubmitted" type="hidden" 
            id="isTimeCardSubmitted" value="${timeCard.isTimeCardSubmitted}"  />
</form:form>
```

here is my controller

```
public String EditTimeCard(Model m, @ModelAttribute("timeCard") TimeCard timeCard){
    System.out.print(timeCard.getIsTimeCardSubmitted());
}
```

here is my model

```
public class TimeCard {
    private boolean isTimeCardSubmitted;

    public TimeCard(){}

}
```

The "isTimeCardSubmitted" input field in the front-end has a value="true"

but when I check the isTimeCardSubmitted in the controller it becomes false.

why is it doing this? how should I fix this problem?

Comment: @varren Yes, I have a setter and getter method for isTimeCardSubmitted

Comment: please, recheck it